# Amcharts 3 - cannot hide category axis of serial chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have several line (serial) charts where I do not want any axes visible, just the graph line itself. I can easily hide the ValueAxes by setting axisThickness to 0, but I cannot get the categoryAxis to hide. I have tried the following:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "axisThickness": 0,
  "axisAlpha": 0
}
```

I can fake hide it by setting "axisColour" to the same colour as the background-color of the containing div. However, it seems to blend with my white graph line when the graph line is running along the hidden axis (consecutive zero values).

How can I hide the category axis properly? Why would "axisThickness" and "axisAlpha" have no effect even though they are in the documentation for CategoryAxis (and they work perfectly for ValueAxis)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to switch off categoryAxis labels: `labelsEnabled: false`?

Here's the reference in official AmCharts docs: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/categoryaxessettings/#labelsEnabled_property

Comment: Yes, I have that set too as I don't want to display any labels. However it doesn't change anything with the axis line itself.